# Make a FOR loop that prints the mean and standard deviation of 100 runif() created variables, making 10 different draws

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Use an explicit FOR loop that repeats the draws and calculation 10 times.
My attempt:

```
x=runif(100)
xmean=mean(x)
for(x in 1:10){xmean=xmean*x}
print(xmean)
```

Comment: Please include your attempt in solving this.

Comment: I added it above

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 10
for(i in seq_len(n)) {
  nums <- runif(100)
  cat(sprintf('\n\nMean for draw %d : %.2f\nSd for draw %d : %.2f', 
              i, mean(nums), i, sd(nums)))
}

#Mean for draw 1 : 0.50
#Sd for draw 1 : 0.28

#Mean for draw 2 : 0.51
#Sd for draw 2 : 0.26

#Mean for draw 3 : 0.49
#Sd for draw 3 : 0.29

#Mean for draw 4 : 0.49
#Sd for draw 4 : 0.29

#Mean for draw 5 : 0.49
#Sd for draw 5 : 0.29

#...
#...
```